# What is wrong with this promise chain? final result should be console.log(4)

Tags: javascript

i am trying to understand promises, and i figured i would start by writing a very simple promise chain, that adds 1 to the previous result.

However, it seems like my functions aren't being recognised as such.
i have declared the functions on the same page, so it should be straightforward enough, yet i keep getting this error.

I have been following web mdn pretty closely and basically just tried to follow their setup.

what am i overlooking here?

I don't feel confident moving on before i can truly play around with the basics.

```js
doSomething()
  .then((result) => doSomethingElse(result))
  .then((newResult) => doThirdThing(newResult))
  .then((finalResult) => {
    console.log(`Got the final result: ${finalResult}`);
  })
  .catch(failureCallback);

function doSomething(){
  a = 1 + 1
  return a
}

function doSomethingElse(param){
  b = param + 1
  return b
}

function doThirdThing(param){
  c = param + 1
  return c
}

function failureCallback(){
  console.log('it did not work')
}
```

Comment: None of these functions return promises

Comment: `what am i overlooking here`...that none of this code involves promises at all. Maybe go back to the tutorials...

Comment: if you followed mdn you should see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) actually .. and your functions should return a Promise object if you want to use its interface

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xbftw67g/ is probably more like what you intended. Making the latter two functions implement promises is optional when you're chaining like this because each .then() continues to the next link of the chain even when a .then() lacks a callback function that returns a Promise object - see the MDN link above. But you do need a promise to kick things off.

Answer (score 1):

None of your functions are returning promise. For the promise chain to work, they must all return promises.

**EDIT**: as @mousetail pointed out, indeed only the first function `doSomething` needs to return a promise. Thereafter, the `then` callbacks create and return the promise for you

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zjaoyvcr/

Comment: This isn't true. Only the first function needs to return a promise.

Comment: thanks for the clarification guys, this will come in handy for practicing!

Answer (score 1):

The `doSomething()` function is not returning the promise. 2 Way to resolve that issue.

**Method - 1 :** Add `async` before `doSomething()`

```
async function doSomething(){
  a = 1 + 1
  return a;
}
```

**Method - 2 :** Return promise in `doSomething()`

```
function doSomething(){
   a = 1 + 1
   return Promise.resolve(a);
}
```

Comment: thanks so much! this a great to test with. I understand that usualy one would use promises when using a fetch(), and there would be returned a resolve or catch based on if the fetch succeeded or not. so when working without an actual fetch, you just fill in the result manually is that correct?